# how to generate the future date / past date using java code with time zone?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I am using the below code and able to generate the date like future and past date by using java code. if you want to add past date just change the method like plus days to minus days

```
    public String yearCalculation() {

        String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat8 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);

        // Get current date
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        System.out.println("date : " + dateFormat.format(currentDate));

        // convert date to localdatetime
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = currentDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println("localDateTime : " + dateFormat8.format(localDateTime));

        // plus one
        localDateTime = localDateTime.plusYears(1).plusMonths(0).plusDays(0);
        // convert LocalDateTime to date
        Date pluseYear = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(pluseYear);
        System.out.println("\n Output of New Date : " + dateFormat.format(pluseYear));
        return strDate;

    }
```

Comment: This is not how self answered question works. ALso How is this related to selenium ?

Comment: BTW: Stop using the outdated classes *SimpleDateFormat* and *java.util.Date*

Comment: Thanks for wanting to share your code. Please put your answer to your question in the answer field below, not in the question, where likely no one will notice it. You should use `ZonedDateTime` in java.time, not `LocalDateTime`. And as @Jens said, you should never use `Date` nor `DateFormat` nor `SimpleDateFormat`. They had severe design problems and are outdated since 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

You are working too hard, and have made a mess of things.

Never use the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use either of the `Date` classes. Never use `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

Never use `LocalDateTime` when trying to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. That class **lacks the context of a time zone or offset**, so it is inherently ambiguous.

You said:

> convert date to localdatetime
>
> convert LocalDateTime to date

No, those conversions are needless and confusing. By involving `LocaDateTime`, you are discarding valuable information (the offset or zone). `LocalDateTime` should generally be one of the *least* used of the *java.time* classes. To track a moment, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`.

To capture the current moment as seen in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

To capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.now( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```

To get the date a year from now, use `LocalDate`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.now( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId ) ;
LocalDate oneYearLater = today.plusYears( 1 ) ;
LocalDate oneYearAgo = today.minusYears( 1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you can generate both future and past data in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //for future date
    LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(1).plusMonths(5).plusDays(4);
    System.out.println("Future Date : "+futureDate);

    //for past dare
    LocalDate pastDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(-1).plusMonths(5).plusDays(4);
    System.out.println("PastDate : "+pastDate);
}
```

Output :
Future Date : 2025-07-10
PastDate : 2023-07-10

Comment: It makes better sense than the code in the question. I am still in doubt how helpful it is, though. Depending on taste many will prefer `.minusYears(1)` as clearer to read than `.plusYears(-1)`.